# How to play notes over one octave at once in one voice on a piano?

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

[image: keys]

In the bass voice, I am supposed to play notes spanning from C to the next but one G at once. Is this even possible with one hand? Should I use the other hand for that G?

I could barely hit the two outer keys with my fingers, but then there is no finger to play the other C...

Comment: Once you get past numbering the fingers over the score, the clefs no longer indicate which hand, only which note. Use the other hand, it's an easier reach.

Comment: I never numbered the fingers, but a friend once told me that the voices should be played with their respective hand

Comment: Ignore that friend's advice - or ask for clarification.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. I assume you mean the G on top of the left hand staff, on the last note?

Comment: it's a G on the bass voice, not F, sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: Your friend is wise, but you can't trust the clefs to always be the same voices. In this case I would consider the B and D in the left hand to both be moving to C, while the D above is moving down to G.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest is to think the top l.h. (bass) note (G) should really have been written under (and belonging to) the treble clef. Then use your right thumb to play it. That's realistically how it ought to have been written.

Comment: Agreed with Tim here - this must be a typo editing-wise as the G3 should be put in RH.

Answer (score 0):

There's an inner melody of a sort at the top of the LH notes.  It could be  emphasized by spreading that last chord.  Or you could accept the notation as showing the musical intention but cheat the G with the RH.   The second way may seem 'easier'.  I suspect the first way could be more effective.

Comment: The first way would be more effective if it was playable with normal hands! And either way, it'll be a thumb.